# Issues printing my groups tree in nodeJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, tree

I'm trying to print all created groups and they're children so it'll look like that:

```
[ [ 'Father1', 'Child1', 'Child2', 'Child3' ],
  [ 'Father1', 'Child1', 'Child4' ],
  [ 'Father1', 'Child1', 'Child5' ] ]
```

The problems I encountered are varied. from: 
var keys = name.keys(o); ^ TypeError: name.keys is not a function to total stack overflow, iv'e debugged the printPath function and it's doing it's job separately but not with my final tree structure.

My tree and print function looks like that:

**groups.js:**

```
class groups {
    constructor() {
        this.root = new Group('root');
    }



    printPath(name){
        this.root.getPath(name)
    }
```

**group.js:**

```
class Group {
    constructor(name, parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent || null;
        this.children = [];
        this.users = new users || null;
    }



     getPath(name) {
        function iter(o, p)  {
            var keys = name.keys(o);
            if (keys.length) {
                return keys.forEach(function (k) {
                    iter(o[k], p.concat(k));
                });
            }
            result.push(p);
        }

        var result = [];
        iter(name, []);
        return result;
    }
```

**Edit:**
**For creating a group i'm using a menu handler function:**

```
function createGroup(callback) {
    rl.question('Add name for father group: \n', (parent) => {
        let parentGroup = programdata.groups.findGroupByName(parent);

        if (!parentGroup) {
            parentGroup = programdata.groups.root;
        }

        rl.question('name of new group\n', (groupName) => {
            parentGroup.setChildren(new Group(groupName, parentGroup));

            console.log(parentGroup);
            callback();
          });
        })
    }
```

**findGroupByNameis a nice recursion i made that finds nested groups (feel free to use!) sitting in class groups.**

```
 findGroupByName(name) {
   if (!name) return null;

   return this._findGroupByNameInternal(this.root, name);
   }


    _findGroupByNameInternal(group, name) {
   if (!group) return null;

   if (group.name === name) return group;

  for (const g of group.children) {
    const result = this._findGroupByNameInternal(g, name);

    if (!result) continue;

    return result;
    }
   }
```

**And setChildren function placed in class Group:**

```
setChildren(child) {
    this.children.push(child);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Thank you for the answer, could you please help me realize your method in my menu handler? iv'e tried this: and it giving me nothing.

```
 function createGroup(callback) {
 rl.question('Add name for father group: \n', (parent) => {
let parentGroup = programdata.groups.findGroupByName(parent);
let treePath = Group.root.printPath();
if (!parentGroup) {
    parentGroup = programdata.groups.root;
}

rl.question('name of new group\n', (groupName) => {
    parentGroup.addChild(new Group(groupName, parentGroup));

    console.log(treePath);
    callback();
   });
 })
}
```

Comment: Please provide some testable input (how you are creating the objects) because I can't seem to find that out just by reading this code.

Comment: Thank you, iv'e updated my post.

Comment: @Anatsu, I have no idea about what is `rl.question` and `programdata`

Comment: your'e right, i didn't explained this,
programdata is an instance of user,users,groups :
const programdata = {
    users: new Users(),
    groups: new Groups(),
    Group: new Group()
};

Comment: in rl.question i'm calling the readline to accept a string input, :
and  of course i'm calling  it at the beginning of the main js file.

const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution.

```
  Treeshow(){
    var node = this.root;
    var depth = '-'
    recurse( node );
    function recurse( node) {
        depth +='-'
        console.log(depth+node.name);

        for (var child in node.children ) {
            recurse(node.children[child]);
        }
        depth  = depth.slice(0, -1);
    }
}
```

that will show my tree just like that:

```
--root
---FooFather
----BarSemiFather
-----FooChild
------BarBaby
```

Answer (score 1):

The root cause you got the error `TypeError: name.keys is not a function` is that a string is passed into `getPath(name)` as argument `name`, you know the JS string object doesn't have a function property *keys*.

I refactor your code and fix some error, here is the testable version. Pls put them into the same folder and run `test.js`.

#### group.js

```
class Group {


constructor(name, parent) {
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = parent || null; // Point to this group's father
    this.children = []; // Children of this group, can be sub-group or string
    if (!!parent) { // Link to the father
      parent.addChild(this);
    }
    // this.users = new users || null; // Useless, remove it.
  }

  addChild(...args) {
    for(let o in args) {
      this.children.push(args[o]);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Recursion to build the tree
   * @param group
   * @returns {*}
   */
  iter(group) {
    let children = group.children;
    if (Array.isArray(children)) { // If the child is a group
      if (children.length > 0) {
        let result = [];
        result.push(group.name);
        for (let child of children) {
          result.push(group.iter(child));
        }
        return result;
      }
      else {
        return [];
      }
    }
    else { // If the group is a string
      return group;
    }
  }

  getPath() {
    return this.iter(this);
  }
}

module.exports = Group;
```

#### groups.js

```
let Group = require('./group');

class Groups {
  constructor() {
    this.root = new Group('root');
  }

  printPath() {
    return this.root.getPath();
  }
}

module.exports = Groups;
```

#### test.js

```
let Group = require('./group');
let Groups = require('./groups');

// Root
let rootGroups = new Groups();

// Group 1
let group1 = new Group('Father1', rootGroups.root);
group1.addChild('Child1', 'Child2', 'Child3');

// Group 2
let group2 = new Group('Father1', rootGroups.root);
group2.addChild('Child1', 'Child4');

// Group 3
let group3 = new Group('Father1', rootGroups.root);
group3.addChild('Child1', 'Child5');

let treePath = rootGroups.printPath();
console.log(treePath);
```

#### The output is:

```
[ 'root',
  [ 'Father1', 'Child1', 'Child2', 'Child3' ],
  [ 'Father1', 'Child1', 'Child4' ],
  [ 'Father1', 'Child1', 'Child5' ] ]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Enjoy it :)